# How to make firefox from snap use `~/.XCompose`

Tags: firefox, snap, compose-key

I use compose key with my own customized compose settings in `~/.XCompose`, which works well everywhere with the exception of firefox from the `snap`.

Is there anyway to "teach" firefox from snap to use `~/.XCompose` or a place to copy that file so that firefox from snap uses it?

Answer (score 6):

For Firefox, you should copy (or better, symlink) the `~/.XCompose` file to `~/snap/firefox/common/`:

```
ln -s ~/.XCompose ~/snap/firefox/common
```

In the general case, you should run

```
snap run --shell {snapname}
env|grep -w HOME
```

and create the symlink to the path indicated in the output of that command.

See also: [Launchpad: Snaps don't respect .XCompose](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1989475).

Comment: It seems that you have to restart your system for the changes to take effect for any snap application. I guess this is something related to snapd daemon.

Comment: To me it suffices to restart Firefox, but who knows what could be different in our environments... I'll keep that in mind, thanks.